# Cascading combo boxes with data bindings

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox, cascading

I have 3 cascading combo boxes which are bound to Data table by their value member. and when i add a new row to data table, i am setting default value of empty string for all columns. So after adding a new row all three combo boxes shows empty selection or empty value which is fine.

Now if i select an item in Combobox 1, combobox 2 still shows the empty value even  though i set combobox2.selectedindex=0 programmatically. i have to manually select/set the 2nd and 3rd combobox values to update the datatable. FYI- all comboboxes (cascading) works fine without databindings.

Could anyone please tell me what is the right method to set values of comboboxes automatically to datatable with databindings (with binding source)?

or should i disable bindings on the indexchanged event of the first combobox and resume binding at the end of 3rd combobox? Please help.

Comment: Did you set cb.BindingContext = New BindingContext()
?

Comment: No, I have somthing like this  Combobox1.DataBindings.Add("Selectedvalue", BS, "CB_Colm1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.onValidation);